# How to force write/delete of a file remotely opened by another user?

Tags: ms-office

I'm writing a process that produces some reports in a file share, which other users can open for reading (csv files, for example). If one has a report opened (in excel) when i'm appending contents to it, i receive an error "The process cannot access the file '[...]' because it is being used by another process".

As an alternative, I can block other users from accessing these reports from the output location, and schedule a copy on a directory in which they'll have access, but that copy would have the same result, since the file copy is still not possible when they have the file opened in that directory.

I cannot close the process that has an handle on the file, since it's on any another computer. The file is not even on the computer running the process, but a remote file share.

That seems to be a common situation, but the only way I can figure out how to manage to have the file copied/written is to wait until it's closed by the other user, which is not acceptable in my situation.

Comment: One option is to schedule the copy, and if it fails, they re-schedule for a future time.  If your process is long-lived (e.g., runs as a service), it might be possible for you to keep the file open in your application and force Excel to open the file read-only (I haven't actually tested this).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an option, but can you serve out the reports via an internal web server?  That would prevent the dreaded "file in use" problem.